# access appdelegate's managedObjectContext in ArrayController of Document

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, core-data, swift, nsmanagedobjectcontext

I am just learning some Core Data and have run into an issue with the idea of having and being able to access separate stores for application-wide and document-only data.

I have a document based application that currently uses some of the entities within a managedObjectContext to populate a table via an NSArrayController.

However, some of these entities should be application wide (part of the experience for all documents - e.g. like data for buttons representing tools that are commonly used)

So for this reason, I pasted in the AppDelegate code for the non-document based application, which creates a separate, application-wide store and managedObjectContext, for the application.  What I want to do is to access this MOC within each NSPersistentDocument (readonly) via an Array Controller (as before) to populate the table view of each opened document.

How would this best be done?  And if this is not the way to populate a TableView that appears in each document from an application-wide MOC, which way should I look for?

P.S I am working in Swift, but am familiar with Objective-C - Thank you for any help!

Comment: Your approach sounds fine to me.

Comment: Thanks - how would you go about getting the application MOC working with the document NSArrayController - should it be something like a singleton?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to Apple you should pass your MOC to the controller. From Core Data Snippets. Note the last two paragraphs.

> By convention, you get a context from a view controller. You must implement your application appropriately, though, to follow this pattern.
>   When you implement a view controller that integrates with Core Data, you can add an NSManagedObjectContext property.
>
> When you create a view controller, you pass it the context it should use. You pass an existing context, or (in a situation where you want the new controller to manage a discrete set of edits) a new context that you create for it. It’s typically the responsibility of the application delegate to create a context to pass to the first view controller that’s displayed.
>
> A view controller typically shouldn’t retrieve the context from a global object such as the application delegate—this makes the application architecture rigid. Neither should a view controller create a context for its own use (unless it’s a nested context). This may mean that operations performed using the controller’s context aren’t registered with other contexts, so different view controllers will have different perspectives on the data.
>
> Sometimes, though, it’s easier or more appropriate to retrieve the context from somewhere other than application or the document, or the view controller. Several objects you might use in a Core Data-based application keep a reference to a managed object context. A managed object itself has a reference to its own context, as do the various controller objects that support Core Data such as array and object controllers (NSArrayController and NSObjectController in OS X, and NSFetchedResultsController in iOS).
>
> Retrieving the context from one of these objects has the advantage that if you re-architect your application, for example to make use of multiple contexts, your code is likely to remain valid. For example, if you have a managed object, and you want to create a new managed object that will be related to it, you can ask original object for its managed object context and create the new object using that. This will ensure that the new object you create is in the same context as the original.

Comment: This worked in the end.  How to actually do it was not trivial.  I created a singleton, which I could then add as a custom object into the xib file and create the bindings etc with the array controller.